# What does POST mean in the following sentence?

Tags: uefi, post

I don't like how this question is phrased, but my main issue here is POST.I know what each of them are beside POST, but how can I explain that? Furthermore, how can I explain UEFI? Isn't that a boot method for an OS or something of the sort? There's legacy and UEFI. But I don't understand POST, mainly but I'd appreciate some hints on UEFI.

> Describe what BIOS, UEFI and POST are and what function they serve?

Comment: Is this homework? If so you should tag it as such as a matter of courtesy. I don't have time to type out a proper answer, but google was helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test

Comment: All these can be found on the millions of computer websites... Wikipedia? Google?

Comment: It's not really "homework" but you can consider it as such, I guess. Thanks for your tip and thanks for the source!

Comment: @MikeWentworth In fairness, the [first directive of asking a good question is research](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking a question on StackExchange should be a last resort, not a first thought. More reading: [How much research effort is expected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Dev, you're most certainly right! Research can help us better discover what we know, so that if we don't understand the research, we can come here and get help both on the question and the research itself. I have done a bit of research, but every now and then I sometimes just need that one on one, live kind of example. You're right, though.

Comment: @EbGreen The homework tag is a meta tag and therefore not allowed. Please don't encourage its use. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Power-on Self Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) or POST is part of the part of the preboot sequence. It tests for common hardware faults.

Generally the results of the POST are indicated by audible beeps. Some more advanced hardware, such as motherboards marketed to overclockers, may have a digital readout that displays a code.